# plataform independent glob function in c/c++

Tags: c++

Does someone know a c/cpp only package that can be an equivalent to the python glob function?

Basically, I am looking for something like this:

```
string startDirectory = "c:\foo\bar\*.txt"
vector<string> filename_list = getFilenameList(startDirectory)
```

Note: Python has a very cute way of doing that:

```
glob(startDirectory)
```

Note: Looking for some implementation what works in ***Windows & Linux***, and has ***no boost*** - just standard c++,c.

Comment: What's wrong with boost??

Comment: I'm sorry but you will find lots of things that Python has a very cute way of doing, and C++ doesn't.

Comment: There's no such thing as directory handling in the C/C++ standard libraries, so I'm afraid you're out of luck. Sidenote, getting the items from a folder using the Win32 API will drive one to seriously consider self-harm.

Comment: You want to have an operating system independent way of accessing the file system without using Boost? You're probably going to have to write it yourself. Boost exists because people got tired of doing just that.

Answer (score 6):

This is one of those questions which has contradictory requirements:

- No libraries
- Portable

One of the major functions of libraries such as Boost is to allow you to write portable code.  Your other option is to write a bunch of code like this:

```
#if defined _WIN32
#include <Windows.h>
std::vector<std::string> glob(const std::string &pattern)
{

}
#else
#include <glob.h>
std::vector<std::string> glob(const std::string &pattern)
{

}
#endif
```

You may not realize just how painful portable code really is.  For example, `std::ifstream` is basically broken on Windows if your users put Unicode characters in their filenames.  This is why we love libraries.

### Note

There is *no* feature in the C or C++ standard libraries that allow you to list the contents of a directory.  If you want to do globbing, you *have* to use platform-specific code.  Your only choice in the matter is whether you write your own bug-ridden code or use a well-tested library like everyone else.